# How can one glimpse other worlds within the many-worlds interpretation?

Tags: time-travel

I'm currently writing 3 separate books that all link together and the way I thought I could do that was with the many worlds interpretation.

One of the books is set in present day where time travel is possible, the second book is set on a different Earth where all the continents are still connected and the third book is set in a poverty stricken world. The books aren't linked but are all set in the same multiverse.

In the time travel book, I want the characters to get glimpses of the other worlds without really realising what they're seeing. None of the characters are historians or scientists so I hope it will be easy to sneakily fit in a few times.

**Is there a way in the many-worlds interpretation to get glimpses--or any information--from one world to another?**

Comment: Time travel is impossible as we understand physics, so feel free to make any rules you want about your time travel.

Comment: OK, I have edited this question and it can/should be answerable now.

Comment: @YoustayIgo, I rolled-back your edit. With it you 1) completely changed the focus of the question of the OP, without his/her agreement and 2) invalidate an already given answer. If indeed the edited version would be more clear, I am not convinced it would be useful to the OP, as s/he may already know the answer. See also the answers of  http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2368/is-this-rejected-edit-in-line-with-se-goals

Comment: As the community sees fit. I'd rather have a somewhat edited and valid question, than have an original question that's unanswerable. Let's wait till OP returns to settle this matter.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because *So, could anyone simply explain the many worlds interpretation?* is a pure physics question.

Comment: I disagree @HDE, this exact problem was dealt with in Neal Stephenon's "Anathem". My advice to the OP is to read reviews of that  book that specifically deal with Stephenon's treatment of the issue, which does feature characters migrating between 3 closely related universes which are all branches of some universal wavefunction.

Comment: @rumguff That comment was before an edit was made, which changed the question's premise, so things are different now.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind Clarke's Law. "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic." Time travel is about as advanced as it gets, so the usual rules don't apply.

> if this kind of time travel is possible, would it take a toll on the body
>   or would it have no impact at all?

I dunno. You're the one who invented the process. You're the one who decided to violate the fundamentals of physics as we know it. So it's up to you to decide whether or not the process damages the subject. What makes a better story?

> Would it effect (sic) animals in the same way?

Hmm. Would it? Does the process somehow require that the subject be intelligent? If so, how much? Maybe a dog can be shifted, but not a rat. What do you think? Time travel breaks all the rules, and at this point no one on this site has any idea how your version works, so how can we tell if it's inconsistent with known science (which doesn't apply anyways)? It's your story.

> Would their bodies reject the devices if they were in certain places
>   on the body?

I hate to sound like a broken record, but why would it? We can make implantable devices today that will not trigger rejection, but what sort of energies do the implants give off? Maybe the tissue in the vicinity, and then the entire subject, will begin to age backwards. It is, after all, sufficiently advanced technology.

It's like the old joke about picking a good accountant - you ask how much 2 plus 2 is. A competent accountant will answer "four", but a great accountant will ask, "How much do you want it to be?". What do you want your story to do?

> When did the land start forming roughly were the UK is now? What is
>   the earliest period they could go to and not fall into the depths of
>   the ocean?

Where is the UK now? I mean with respect to the Cretaceous period? (I'm not ignoring your question. I'm just trying to get you to think about how you define what, exactly, it is that you're asking.) It's not like there is some sort of grid pattern on the earth to establish, say, the Greenwich Meridian. The surface of the earth slides around, of course, but the interior, or at least the core, isn't a fixed ball, either, since it has currents. And the length of both the year and the day have changed during the eons, so you can't reference things to the solar system, either. For what it's worth, [this map](http://www.phschool.com/atschool/phsciexp/active_art/continental_drift/) can be adjusted to show the relative outlines of the continents over the last couple of hundred million years, and it suggests that the current location of the British Isles sits on a latitude that hasn't had much water over the period of interest.

How about this? The implants can be "locked" to an in-situ bit of rock or fossil, and will track it as the implant slides back through time. When the fossil separates into its parts (the living organism is assembled from an assortment of sources as it eats and drinks, so going backwards it will suddenly dissolve). If the fossil is a marine organism, of course, the implant will end up in the water, so you have to choose carefully.

Answer (score 0):

**In reality, no, but for time travelers, why not?**

As the first answer pointed out, time travel breaks the laws of physics as we know them. At this point in time in our universe, MWI is a *theory* we have no way of confirming.

The good news is that, if time travel were possible, it is very plausible that glimpsing (or even traveling to) other universes would be too. Whatever allows your time machine to "unlock" itself from the normal flow of time could conceivably free it from being locked to the track of this particular universe as well.

There isn't a scientific way to explain how this would work (because again, science says it's impossible), but I suspect that if there were one, it would come (like MWI itself) from quantum physics.